# Is OTB sufficient for the evaluation of Random Forests or bagging classifiers generally, or is cross validation applicable here as well?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

What I understand is that out-of-bag evaluation tests each individual classifier's performance on never before seen data due to the nature bootstrapping, and it does so to each classifier in the ensemble - but only once. Yet in K-fold cross-validation the model is evaluated multiple times on different subsets of the depending on the number of folds, so does that apply here too? Same goes with boosting and stacking classifiers, aren't those types of models prone to overfitting or overly optimistic performance as much as other individual models?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-bag and k-fold cross validation are fundamentally different. As you have explained, out-of-bag validates the model on data not used in the training (since bootstrap is used to select data to train), but k-fold splits the data into k separate folds and trains/validates over all k folds.

The advantage of out-of-bag estimation is its computational speed, but k-fold estimation is usually a much better estimate. If you are interested in a quick evaluation of performance, especially to compare several methods, then out-of-bag is fine. Otherwise, I recommend using k-fold.

You can read more about it in this paper: [On the overestimation of random forest’s out-of-bag error](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6078316/)